# Migrating Parse files from Gridstore to S3

Tags: parse-platform

We migrated the data(without files) to **mLab** and **Heroku**. So the old files are still on **Parse**.

Since then, any new file added goes into **Gridstore**, which is the default file storage for mLab.

Now I migrated old parse files from Parse to an **S3 Bucket** using [sashido](https://mv.sashido.io/)

The files are migrated and are accessible using **S3Adapter** in **Heroku**.

But the files on **Gridstore** are not accessible now. How can I migrate them to the same **S3 bucket** and change references in **mLab**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're interested in the solution I've tried. It's not a simple operation, but I migrated successfully 3 databases with my parse server configuration.

It's based in a PHP script (with the Parse PHP SDK) that runs through every object, it gets the file from Parse.com and sets it (with any of your adapter configuration) in your own server.

The script looks like:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    
    $fileField = $argv[1];
    $class     = $argv[2];
    
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Parse\ParseObject;
    use Parse\ParseQuery;
    use Parse\ParseACL;
    use Parse\ParsePush;
    use Parse\ParseUser;
    use Parse\ParseInstallation;
    use Parse\ParseException;
    use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
    use Parse\ParseFile;
    use Parse\ParseCloud;
    use Parse\ParseClient;
    
    $app_id     = "******";
    $rest_key   = "******";
    $master_key = "******";
    
    ParseClient::initialize($app_id, $rest_key, $master_key);
    ParseClient::setServerURL('http://localhost:1338/', 'parse');
    
    $query = new ParseQuery($class);
    $query->ascending("createdAt"); // it's just my preference
    $query->exists($fileField);
    $query->limit(1);
    
    $count = $query->count();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i = $i + 1) {
        try {
            $query->skip($i);
            // get Entry
            $entryWithFile = $query->first();
            
            // get file
            $parseFile = $entryWithFile->get($fileField);
            // filename
            $fileName  = $parseFile->getName();

            // if the file is hosted in Parse, do the job, otherwise continue with the next one
            if (strpos($fileName, "tfss-") === false) {
                echo "\nThis is already an internal file, skipping...";
                continue;
            }
            
            $newFileName = str_replace("tfss-", "", $fileName);
            $binaryFile  = file_get_contents($parseFile->getURL());
            
            $newFile = ParseFile::createFromData($binaryFile, $newFileName);
            
            $entryWithFile->set($fileField, $newFile);
            $entryWithFile->save(true);
            
            echo "\nFile saved\n";
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // The conection with mongo or the server could be off for some second, let's retry it ;)
            sleep(10);
            continue;
        }
    }
    
    echo "\n";
    echo "END!";
    
?>
```

set your parse url correctly.

Imagine you want to migrate the file from class `_User` with field `imageProfile`, so be sure that you pass `$fileField = "imageProfile"; $class = "_User"`.

Run that code for any field per class.

I did a dumb solution to work in parallel, which would be skipping steps in the `for` loop, for example:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    
    $index     = $argv[1];
    $of        = $argv[2];
    $fileField = $argv[3];
    $class     = $argv[4];
    
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Parse\ParseObject;
    use Parse\ParseQuery;
    use Parse\ParseACL;
    use Parse\ParsePush;
    use Parse\ParseUser;
    use Parse\ParseInstallation;
    use Parse\ParseException;
    use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
    use Parse\ParseFile;
    use Parse\ParseCloud;
    use Parse\ParseClient;
    
    $app_id     = "********";
    $rest_key   = "********";
    $master_key = "********";
    
    ParseClient::initialize($app_id, $rest_key, $master_key);
    ParseClient::setServerURL('http://localhost:1338/', 'parse');
    
    $query = new ParseQuery($class);
    $query->ascending("createdAt");
    $query->exists($fileField);
    $query->limit(1);
    
    $count = $query->count();
    for ($i = $index; $i < $count; $i = $i + $of) {
        try {
            $query->skip($i);
            // get Entry
            $entryWithFile = $query->first();
            
            // get file
            $parseFile = $entryWithFile->get($fileField);
            // filename
            $fileName  = $parseFile->getName();

            // if the file is hosted in Parse, do the job, otherwise continue with the next one
            if (strpos($fileName, "tfss-") === false) {
                echo "\nThis is already an internal file, skipping...";
                continue;
            }
            
            $newFileName = str_replace("tfss-", "", $fileName);
            $binaryFile  = file_get_contents($parseFile->getURL());
            
            $newFile = ParseFile::createFromData($binaryFile, $newFileName);
            
            $entryWithFile->set($fileField, $newFile);
            $entryWithFile->save(true);
            
            echo "\nFile saved\n";
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // The conection with mongo or the server could be off for some second, let's retry it ;)
            sleep(10);
            continue;
        }
    }
    
    echo "\n";
    echo "END!";
    
?>
```

so if you configure `$fileField` and `$class` as before, and you can open 3 threads and run:

> `php migrator.php 0 3 "imageProfile" "_User"`
>
> `php migrator.php 1 3 "imageProfile" "_User"`
>
> `php migrator.php 2 3 "imageProfile" "_User"`

so you will have loops running like:

object 0, 3, 6

object 1, 4, 7

object 2, 5, 8

Good luck, and be quick! It's going to shut down in a few days.